# Add an Aggregating Timeline to a Plotly Scatter Mapbox

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, geopandas

So I have a scatter mapbox that displays the locations of all people with a real estate license. What I want to do is have a timeline animation that would show (aggregate?) the locations on the map of those whose licenses are expired (as you scroll time forward). So basically the timeline would go from today's date to say 10 years in the future, and as you scroll further and further, more locations show up because they fall within the parameter of being expired.

Here is the code I currently have, I can make modifications to the csv, but I dont know how to go about this, thanks for any and all help.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly 

df = gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\FT4\Desktop\FT Imported Data\Lic_expire Data.csv")


px.set_mapbox_access_token(open(r"C:\Users\FT4\Desktop\FT Imported Data\Map API Token Keys\Maps.mapbox_token.txt").read())
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df,
                        lat=df.Latitude.astype(str).astype(float), 
                        lon=df.Longitude.astype(str).astype(float), 
                        color="License Type",
                        #color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                        mapbox_style = 'carto-positron', 
                       zoom=4,
                        hover_name='name1',
                        hover_data= ["License Type", "Expiration Date"],
                       
                        #size = df.Expiration_Scale.astype(str).astype(int)
                       )
                                         
fig.update_layout(
    margin=dict(l=10, r=10, t=10, b=10),
    
)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not present any data, I created a data frame with a dummy license ID, license acquisition date, expiration date after 5 years, and license type based on the data in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#basic-example-with-plotly-express), applied your code to that data frame, and set the animation frame to the expiration date. The slider is detailed as it will be in units of the expiration date. If you want to see this more collectively, you could add a column that converts the expiration date to year and month, and set that column to the animation frame.

```
import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta
import numpy as np
import random
import plotly.express as px

px.set_mapbox_access_token(open("mapbox_api_key.txt").read())
df = px.data.carshare()
df['Acquisition Date'] = random.choices(pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2020-01-01', freq='1D'), k=len(df))
df['Expiration Date'] = df['Acquisition Date'].apply(lambda x: x +relativedelta.relativedelta(years=5))
df['License ID'] = np.random.randint(100000,190000, (len(df),))
df['License Type'] = random.choices(['Sales','Broker'], k=len(df))
df['Expiration Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Expiration Date'])
df['Expiration Date'] = df['Expiration Date'].apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df,
                        lat="centroid_lat",
                        lon="centroid_lon",
                        color="License Type",
                        size_max=50,
                        hover_name='License ID',
                        animation_frame='Expiration Date',
                        #animation_group='License Type',
                        mapbox_style='carto-positron',
                        hover_data=["License Type", "Expiration Date"],
                        zoom=9
                       )
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=True,
    height=600,    
    margin=dict(l=10, r=10, t=20, b=10),
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help r-beginners! So basically I am almost there with what you made, the only thing I really need is for it to show all locations (rows) where the expiration date is less than or equal to the date on the timeline axis. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with express. So, if it were possible, you would need code to use `graph_objects` to relate the data after the relevant expiration date to a frame by date.